# Thread join hangs

Tags: c++, multithreading

Thread join is hanging in case of single producer and multiple consumer case.
I am attaching the codebase below:

1) This is the Consumer Thread

```
class ConsumerThread-
{
    wqueue<WorkItem*>& m_queue;
-
  public:
    ConsumerThread(wqueue<WorkItem*>& queue) : m_queue(queue) {}

    std::thread start() {
      return std::thread( [=] {runThr();} );
    }
-
    void runThr() {
        // Remove 1 item at a time and process it. Blocks if no items are-
        // available to process.
        for (int i = 0;; i++) {
            printf("thread %lu, loop %d - waiting for item...\n",-
                  std::this_thread::get_id(), i);
            WorkItem* item = (WorkItem*)m_queue.remove();
            printf("thread %lu, loop %d - got one item\n",-
                  std::this_thread::get_id(), i);
            printf("thread %lu, loop %d - item: message - %s, number - %d\n",-
                  std::this_thread::get_id(), i, item->getMessage(),-
                   item->getNumber());
            delete item;
        }
    }
};
```

2) This is Work Item

```
class WorkItem
{
    std::string m_message;
    int    m_number;
-
  public:
    WorkItem(const char* message, int number)-
          : m_message(message), m_number(number) {}
    ~WorkItem() {}
-
    const char* getMessage() { return m_message.c_str(); }
    int getNumber() { return m_number; }
};
```

3).  This class is has the queue where the producer pushes and consumers consume the WorkItem.

```
template <typename T> class wqueue
{
    std::list<T>                  m_queue;
    std::mutex               m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable  m_condv;-

  public:
    wqueue() {}
    ~wqueue() {}

    void add(T item) {
        m_mutex.lock();
        m_queue.push_back(item);
        m_condv.notify_one();
        m_mutex.unlock();
    }

    T remove() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_mutex);
        while(m_queue.size() == 0)
            m_condv.wait(lk);
        T item = m_queue.front();
        m_queue.pop_front();
        return item;
    }
    int size() {
        m_mutex.lock();
        int size = m_queue.size();
        m_mutex.unlock();
        return size;
    }
};
```

4) This is the class containing the main function

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // Process command line arguments
    if ( argc != 2 ) {
        printf("usage: %s <iterations>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    int iterations = atoi(argv[1]);

    // Create the queue and consumer (worker) threads
    wqueue<WorkItem*>  queue;
    ConsumerThread* thread1 = new ConsumerThread(queue);
    ConsumerThread* thread2 = new ConsumerThread(queue);

    std::thread t1 = thread1->start();
    std::thread t2 = thread2->start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    // Add items to the queue
    WorkItem* item;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        item = new WorkItem("abc", 123);
        queue.add(item);
        item = new WorkItem("def", 456);
        queue.add(item);
        item = new WorkItem("ghi", 789);
        queue.add(item);
    }
```

The  t1.join() and t2.join() hangs mentioned in the section 4.

Comment: `join()` (wait for the execution of the thread ends) and then add items to the queue? It looks strange.

Comment: When you execute `t1.join()` and `t2.join()`, there are no items in the queue, so the threads will hang at `WorkItem* item = (WorkItem*)m_queue.remove();`

Comment: The programs is actually hanging at join() and not remove(). Here is the backtrace.    #0  0x0000003c0200822d in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff7d9f09a in __gthread_join (this=0x7fffffffe240)
    at /opt/tools/compile/gcc-4.5.3/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:658
#2  std::thread::join (this=0x7fffffffe240) at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/src/thread.cc:61
#3  0x00000000004014cc in main ()

Comment: Really? did you check it by printing something in `runThr()`?

Comment: thread 139685266667264, loop 0 - waiting for item...
thread 139685256177408, loop 0 - waiting for item...
Below is the print in runThr() statement.

Comment: Why do you think they won't print `thread %lu, loop %d - got one item`? It shows that it hangs in `m_queue.remove()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your consumer thread has no terminating condition so it runs forever:

```
for (int i = 0;; i++) // never ends
```

Joining a thread won't magically make it break out of its loop, you need to set an *ended* flag or something.

Also when the `wqueue` is empty all threads trying to `remove()` an element will block:

```
    while(m_queue.size() == 0)
        m_condv.wait(lk);
```

You try to `join()` the threads *before* putting anything in them.

Comment: I have made it for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) .Still it doesn't work.

Comment: I called below code after producer code and it worked. Thanks for you reply.
    WorkItem* item;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        item = new WorkItem("abc", 123);
        queue.add(item);
        item = new WorkItem("def", 456);
        queue.add(item);
        item = new WorkItem("ghi", 789);
        queue.add(item);
    }                                                                                                                   t1.join();
    t2.join();

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the behaviour, calling `join()` on a thread object will simply wait until the thread finishes before continuing. Your problem is rather that your threads don't terminate, which is a whole different issue.

In particular in a producer-consumer setup, both peers typically sit and wait for work. Unless you explicitly tell them not to wait for work any longer, they will sit there forever! If you in turn wait for them to finish, you will also wait forever, which is your problem. You need to signal them to stop looping and additionally you might have to interrupt them from waiting for work.